Register a web app (no PWA) as destination with "send to" e.g. for scanning
Can a normal web application (no PWA) that is installed on the home screen be registered as destination with "send to" on mobile devices?
Objective: I want to be able to send scans produced by a native scanning app via "send to" to the backend of the app associated with the current web-session as the scan must be associated with the user currently logged in in the web app.
I already wrote a scanning module in the app that takes fotos and assembles them to a PDF but native scanning apps have much more functionality that would take me ages to implement, as I am more into desktop programming. Apart from that the idea came up with the question "why write something that already exists much better than I ever can write it".
I have no idea if registering a web app with "send to" is even possible on Android and iOS but before I give this idea up I want to ask the community.
Thanks in advance for ideas and help!
